# Simple SELECT in C# throws "Incorrect syntax near '='"

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I am trying to get data from my database using the **SqlDataReader**

But I am getting a syntax error **"System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near '='"** and I don't know what its about.

Here is my code

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Submission_Attachment as Path from Tasks where Submission_FileName =" + FileName, con);
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
   FilePath = reader["Path"].ToString();
   TextBox1.Text = FilePath;
}
```

There error shows at **reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();**

Comment: You need to be using parameterized queries

Comment: Several people described a fix for your problem but I think it is also probably worth mentioning that the error was coming from SQL Server and it was a complaint about the query you built.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use parameters to avoid SQL injections.

Your current string is not surrounded by single quotes, which is causing the error.

```
string sqlText = "Select Submission_Attachment as Path from Tasks where Submission_FileName = @fileName";
cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlText, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fileName", FileName);
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Answer (score 3):

`Submission_FileName` is probably a string (varchar) field. You need to wrap the value in single quotes:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Submission_Attachment as Path from Tasks where Submission_FileName = '" + FileName + "'", con);
```

Still you need to use parameterized queries to counteract SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Submission_Attachment as Path from Tasks where Submission_FileName = @filename", con);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@filename", SqlDbType.VarChar, [varchar length here]).Value = FileName;
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
   FilePath = reader["Path"].ToString();
   TextBox1.Text = FilePath;
}
```